# Firebase React: Remove Item (Map) from array in firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to remove a map item from an array in firebase.  From what I understand with firebase - you are unable to delete the item based on the index. Should I structure this a different way or is there an easier way to remove a specific object from the array?  Thank you

**Error**: 'No document to update: '

[image]

````
  const listingRef = doc(db, 'users', 'savedListings');

  const deleteListing = async () => {
    try {
      await updateDoc(listingRef, {
        savedListings: deleteField()
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  };```
````

Comment: hi, i need help in creating react array map in firebase, can you please share source code for this. i am trying for the past 3 months but can't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

The `doc()` takes path to a document that should be `users/test@user.com` in this case. While you can use [`arrayRemove()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) to remove elements from an array field you cannot delete an object from an array unless you know the exact value that object including all the fields.

```
const listingRef = doc(db, 'users', 'USER_EMAIL'); // USER_EMAIL is document ID

const deleteListing = async () => {
  try {
    await updateDoc(listingRef, {
      savedListings: arrayRemove("THAT_OBJECT")
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
};
```

If you don't have that exact object, then you'll have to read the document, manually remove the element from array and update the document back.

Comment: If I pass in the ${user.email} I can delete the entire array which is not optimal.

Would I be better off not using an array to store this data perhaps?

Comment: @ClintBriley an array seems ideal to store user's addresses. Just to delete a specific one from that array, you would have to use either of the methods mentioned in my answer - fetching the document, removing the address and updating back the modified array or use `arrayRemove()` if you have that address object on client side.

Comment: If I were trying to remove the entire map within the array would I run the "arrayRemove()" on each "address" "beds" "baths" "price" etc..?

Comment: @ClintBriley you'll need to know exact value of that map e.g. `arrayRemove({ address: "", beds: 4, ...exactValueOfOtherFields })`

Comment: If I only want to delete the object from my array and never update fields within my object, do I still need to remove every field from within that specific object? Not sure what the best way to go about this is.  Seems like a pain to not be able to delete the object based off the index. Thank you 