# Delete an array element using Firebase 9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I've a simple document in my Firestore collection.

```
{
  "posts": ["0", "1", "3"],
  "title": "Delete an array element"
}
```

I know how to delete an entire document using the auto generated Direbase doc id but I'm not sure how do I delete a specific element in an `array`, let's here I'd like to delete the `1`.

And I don't want to use `updateDoc` for this to work. 
Using Javascript for the integration.

[image: Database structure]

Comment: What is the programming language you're using? Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo I've added the firestore structure and I am using Javascript

Comment: Maybe this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073) will also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `updateDoc()` function is required to update a document. You can use [`arrayRemove()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) function to remove an element from the array.

```
import { doc, updateDoc, arrayUnion, arrayRemove } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = doc(db, "collection", "docId");

await updateDoc(docRef, {
    posts: arrayRemove("1") // removes "1" from the array 
});
```

Do note that if you have an array of objects then you must pass the entire object to be removed in `arrayRemove()`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, Though I have one question, How can I delete an object. Cause I see you've used an arrayRemove function and basically we have pass the exact element for to remove that element. Thanks.

Comment: @random_18 in case of array of objects you need to know the exact object. If you only know value of a single property then you cannot use `arrayRemove()`. You will then have to read the document first and update manually as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71819481)